# Merge button is disabled after all the checks passed on Github

Tags: github

Github is blocking all the pull requests from being merged, even though all the checks passed. There is no configuration for reviewer approval on the repo.

After all the checks passed, it still shows **Required statuses must pass before merging**. If I close this PR and reopen it, then the button is enabled and I can merge it normally. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you set branch protection rules for status checks on the branch you're merging into? Check the repo's Settings > Branches > [branch name] > `Require status checks to pass before merging` and see if you're requiring any old/outdated status checks there.

Comment: Yes, there is a rule for that. But still, with the status checks passing, the merge is not enabled

Comment: This looks like a job for GitHub support.